# Working remotely in Unity with git repository with my mate. Sync issue

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, synchronization, repository

Long story short I worked on a game in Unity. Pushed nicely to git repo. Then my mate worked on the project (but he worked on an older version and apparently didn't pull before starting to work) and pushed his changes. He's worked on a different scene but his MainScene is different then mine. So now when I pull his commit my MainScene is back to where it was, discharging all my previous changes.

I made a new branch for my work now. I tried to fork. Nothing really helps and it's a really hard problem to google. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. When he pushes and there are changes in the repo, git doesn't accept the changes, and requests to update the local repository first.

Comment: yeah that's apparently the error he was getting when we talked last night but then he told me that he bashed it up and committed anyway...

Comment: Then it should be his job to recover your changes not yours. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely, your mate used `git push -f`, forcing `git` to replace your commit by his own. He should have pulled (and hence merged) your changes first.

Good news: Your changes are probably not lost.

### Getting back your changes

Assuming both of you worked on the `master` branch, use `git reflog master` to find a history of commits that your HEAD was pointing to. Then you can use `git branch master <commit-hash> -f` to make your own branch point to said commit again (pick the last one that was "yours"). This, at the very first step, restores your local changes.

EDIT: note, you cannot change `master` in this way if it is currently checked out. Check out anything else before (for example `git checkout HEAD^`, doesn't matter which). After the `git branch master ... -f`, checkout your new master with `git checkout master`.

### fsck

If `git reflog` doesn't show up anything, which can happen even though your commit is still around somewhere, then you can try `git fsck --dangling` to list all local commits that have nothing pointing to them. See `git help fsck` how to proceed. A usefull command is

```
git fsck --dangling | grep commit | awk -- '{print $3}' | xargs git log
```

### Pull

Now, you should be able to pull his changes in. If you then do a `git pull`, it should really merge his and your changes, and you should be fine.

Comment: What I've done is just to go back to my working copy and ask this question but I'll do what you said and see how it goes. I'll keep you posted. Cheers!

Comment: Guess you two have some communicating to do. :) You are speaking of a "working copy" - do you have a separate, non-git version of your files on your HDD?

Comment: Hey! When I do the git branch master <commit-hash> -f I get fatal: Cannot force update the current branch. Any ideas why? Please

Comment: Apparently he's pulled before committing but my scene is still changed... Ech just another bright side of a group project.

Comment: AnoE no we didn't have a copy like this but I think I'll get one next time.